# Why is code working fine locally, but takes longer on Google App Engine Flexible Environment?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, dockerfile, app-engine-flexible

I have this Node.JS application. I made its docker image from this base: https://hub.docker.com/r/bcgovimages/alpine-node-libreoffice
When I compare the performance by running the image locally and deploying it on Google Cloud App Engine (GAE) Flexible Environment, there isn't a big difference expect for this function:

```js
const getWordDocument = async (req, res) => {

    try {

        const doc = new Document(); // This is a Word Document created using docx npm library. I omitted previous code for readability.

        const filename = uuidv4();

        // Saving in Docx format
        await Packer.toBuffer(doc).then((buffer) => {
            fs.writeFileSync(`./assets/${filename}.docx`, buffer);
        });

        const environment = process.env.NODE_SERVER_ENV || "PROD";

        // Executing libreoffice for .docx to .pdf conversion

        exec(`${environment == "PROD" ? "libreoffice" : "soffice"} --headless --convert-to pdf ./assets/${filename}.docx --outdir ./assets/`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) {
                console.error(`Error converting file: ${error}`);
                return;
            }
            // Uploading docs to Storage Bucket and sending their URLs back in response.
            uploadDocs(filename)
                .then((urls) => {
                    res.json({ urls: urls });
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.error('Error uploading files:', error);
                    res.status(500).send('Error uploading files');
                })
        });

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error retrieving file:', error);
        res.status(500).send('Error retrieving file');
    }

};


async function uploadDocs(filename) {
    try {
        const bucketName = 'blah-blah-blah';
        const folderName = 'purchase';
        const uniqueIdentifier = uuidv4();
        const objectNameDocx = `${folderName}/${uniqueIdentifier}/Document.docx`;
        const objectNamePdf = `${folderName}/${uniqueIdentifier}/Document.pdf`;

        const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName);

        await Promise.all([
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const docxFile = bucket.file(objectNameDocx);
                const docxStream = docxFile.createWriteStream({
                    metadata: {
                        contentType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'
                    }
                });
                fs.createReadStream(`./assets/${filename}.docx`)
                    .pipe(docxStream)
                    .on('error', reject)
                    .on('finish', resolve);
            }),
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const pdfFile = bucket.file(objectNamePdf);
                const pdfStream = pdfFile.createWriteStream({
                    metadata: {
                        contentType: 'application/pdf'
                    }
                });
                fs.createReadStream(`./assets/${filename}.pdf`)
                    .pipe(pdfStream)
                    .on('error', reject)
                    .on('finish', resolve);
            })
        ]);

        fs.unlinkSync(`./assets/${filename}.docx`);
        fs.unlinkSync(`./assets/${filename}.pdf`);

        const docxSignedUrl = await bucket.file(objectNameDocx).getSignedUrl({
            action: 'read',
            expires: Date.now() + 60 * 60 * 1000,
        });

        const pdfSignedUrl = await bucket.file(objectNamePdf).getSignedUrl({
            action: 'read',
            expires: Date.now() + 60 * 60 * 1000,
        });

        return [...docxSignedUrl, ...pdfSignedUrl];
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error uploading files:', error);
        throw error;
    }
}
```

In my observation, the specific part ".docx to .pdf conversion using libreoffice" is taking a lot longer. Exec command may be a culprit. Because other parts of the application (interacting with storage bucket, apis etc) are working fine without delays.

When using this function, the whole operation takes:

- Local Env: 10-12 seconds
- Local Docker Image: 10-12 seconds
- Docker Image deployed to GAE: 2-3 minutes

My laptop is 8GB RAM, intel i5 12th Gen, so I don't think it's fast enough. I'm on a free quota on Google Cloud so maybe I'm not issued much resources? Can somebody point out the issue?

Here's the dockerfile:

```
FROM bcgovimages/alpine-node-libreoffice:latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

# Copy the rest of your application code
COPY . .

# Expose the port your app runs on
EXPOSE 8080

# Command to run your application
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

app.yaml:

```yaml
runtime: custom
env: flex

entrypoint: node index.js
handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: auto
    secure: always
env_variables:
  NODE_SERVER_ENV: "PROD"
```

I have to convert document on server because I can't embed fonts in MS Word Document, and converting to PDF here helps retain fonts.

Thank you.

Comment: You compare something not comparable!! By default you have 2vCPU and 1,6Gb of memory on App Engine flex: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/reference/app-yaml?tab=python#general
Your local cpu is 10 vCPU and 8Gb of mem. In addition, the cloud CPU are slower than yours: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/cpu-platforms Your local CPU should be 500 - 1000Mhz faster. Try by testing your container locally by limiting the number of CPU,  you should be closer to App Engine timings.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere - I think the default is one vCPU and 0.6 GB memory. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/reference/app-yaml?tab=php#resource-settings

Comment: Try changing `app.yaml` and declare the `cpu` and `memory_bg` values. Then retest. Start with CPU = 2 and memory_gb = 2. Increase as required.

Comment: I missed the "default" column!! thanks @JohnHanley

Comment: Hi, that was spot on. Changing resources to 4vCPUs and 4GB memory brings the whole operation down to under 11 seconds! Wonder what my bill would look like. Still trying to understand their pricing :P Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: FYI: There's no free tier for app engine flex.

Comment: It's costing me about £8/day to just keep the service up. For libre office usage, I can create a micro service like a server less function for optimized cost?

Answer (score 0):

Change `app.yaml` and declare the `cpu` and `memory_bg` values. Then retest.

Start with cpu = 2 and memory_gb = 2. Increase as required.